# laravel, create heartbeat for task scheduling

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks

I have a task scheduled to run every hour, and I want to create from inside that task another task scheduler than runs every minute, which job is to send like a heartbeat for the main task to make sure it is not stuck for a long time, is there any possible way to do it because I can't find any resource talking about this.

Comment: How can you *make sure it is not stuck for a long time*?

Comment: When the heartbeat scheduler runs every minute, he updates the datetime inside the database, and in other part I check if the heartbeat is sent regularely, if I didn't get the heartbeart for an hour I will consider it stuck.

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this for scheduled tasks. However you can have a scheduled task that will add a job to the queue and execute it with a queue worker with sufficiently large timeout and retry, and retry after times. That will give you control on whether you want to kill the task after it's running for e.g. 1 hour and if you want to retry it or not. Trying to solve this with the task scheduler will require lots of changes to your long running task just to accommodate the "heartbeat"